# want to make the select boxes selected in perl

Tags: perl, template-toolkit

i want to make the select boxes selected based on the values from the database.

code :

```
my $bug_id = $cgi->param('id');

#query for fetching the datas from the table category_bug_map for updating the select box
my $selectboxcategoryQuery = "SELECT os,cp,service FROM category_bug_map WHERE     bug_id=$bug_id";


my $statusQuery2 = $dbslave -> prepare($selectboxcategoryQuery);
$statusQuery2 -> execute();
my($OS,$CP,$ser) = $statusQuery2 -> fetchrow_array();

$vars->{'select_os'} = $OS;
$vars->{'select_cp'} = $CP;
$vars->{'select_ser'} = $ser;
```

I want to use the variables in template file to make the select boxes selected(updated).How can i perform this?

Comment: could anyone pls answer this?

Comment: It usually helps if you want more than 30 seconds for an answer…

Comment: Also, you haven't told us what kind of template you're using.  But the process is simple: pass `$vars` to the template, then in the template inspect `$vars` and vary your output based on it.

Comment: i tried with the following code :

    [% FOREACH category IN sub_category1 %]
                                <option value="[% category %]"
                                [% "selected" IF category == select_os%] >
                                     [% category %]
                                </option>
                        [%  END %]

And got the desired result.

Comment: [% FOREACH category IN sub_category1 %] 
<option value = "[% category %]" [% IF category == select_os %]selected[ % END % ]>[% category %]</option> 
[% END %]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jenifer try this:-

[% FOREACH category IN sub_category1 %] [% category %] [% END %]